# What is xscale and yscale?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, scatter-plot

I am reading some code, therein I noticed a big change while using `pyplot.xaxis('log')` and `pyplot.yaxis('log')`. So the basic scatter plot looks like this:
[image]

and after adding:

```
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
```

the graph looks like this:
[image]

I went to look the documentation but there was not enough explanation about it. like, What is `xscale` and `yscale` and what is the function of their respective parameters like `log`, `linear`, `symlog` and `logit`?

[image]

I am absolutely new in graph and matplotlib. I have no good knowledge of these, can you please help me out with this and explain what is `xscale`, `yscale`  and what is the function of their respective parameters like `log`, `linear`, `symlog` and `logit`?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the scale of your y and x-axis to be *logarithmic* in scale.

Normally every `y` distance on your axis your values increment by a fixed amount, example:

```
   0 at 0cm
   1 at 1cm
   2 at 2cm  
  ...
1000 at 10m
```

With logarythmic the values scale by a magnitude. Example for powers of 10:

```
   0 at 0cm
   1 at 1cm
  10 at 2cm
 100 at 3cm
1000 at 4cm etc.
```

It is a way to display widely spread data in a compacter format.

See [logarithmic scale on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_scale)

Your data has a cluster of values and an outlier - by printing with a logarithmic scale your *blob* gets shown over distance `whatever` and the big distance between the *blob* and the outlier takes less screenarea due to it being logarithmic.

Other examples for log-plots:

- https://plot.ly/python/log-plot/
- [matplotlib.pyplot.xscale.html](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xscale.html)
- [matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html)

and

- [matplotlib.scale.LogScale](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.LogScale)